# What is purpose of DB Browser(dbbrowser.aspx) under admin tool?

Tags: admin-pages

Want to know main purpose of `dbbrowser.aspx` page under admin tool. It looks similar to `content editor` interface.

What are main advantages of this tool over content editor?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An often overlooked benefit of it, is it's capability to browse *any* Sitecore Item structure. While obvious, many people don't consider that an Item *needs* to inherit a lot of fields/base templates for the Content Editor to be able to navigate them properly. Security, Workflow, Item Statistics and so on.

The `DBBrowser` tool needs none of that. It just allows you to browse the item parent/child hierarchy and shows you what it finds.

Answer (score 6):

A quick way to browse through the separate Sitecore databases. It is pretty lightweight and supports previewing of item’s fields, versions, languages etc. The DB Browser also allows preview of the file system.

Comment: The delete of subitems is present on Sitecore. If you click on an item that has subitems, from the Home tab where the Delete icon is present, there is a dropdown and you can click on it to delete subitems (https://ibb.co/wJQYY8D). However, I've seen that deleting bulk item from dbbrowser is much faster than from the content editor. Maybe, through dbbrowser, it bypass the different events

Comment: I updated my answer, you are right.

Answer (score 6):

It is also usefull in situations when Content Editor does not work because of broken item. You can use `dbbrowser.aspx` to navigate to that item and